# How to share images to Gmail from internal memory?

Tags: android

In the following i was succesful in saving screenshot in internal memory. But Gmail and many other apps say they cant share an empty file except whatsapp and bluetooth. I know internal memory does not allow sharing between apps. I used Environment.getExternalDirectory. 
My aim is to available it to Gmail.
I have read all the previous questions and I couldnt find the solution with this.
How do I share and whats the mistake? What i'm missing here?
The getExternalStorageDirectory() gives path to sdcard0 which is in case my internal memory here and my sdcard is sdcard1.

```
public void captureScreen()
{


    GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback()
    {

        @Override
        public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot)
        {


            try
            {

                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MapScreenshot"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png");
                snapshot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);

                Toast.makeText(Map.this, "Path Captured as Image, saved in" + path,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Image not saved", "");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }




    };

    googleMap.snapshot(callback);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_share_text).setPositiveButton(R.string.share_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //user shared
            Intent sharingIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(path));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share Image Using"));
        }
    }).setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //user cancelled
        }
    }).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well try This Code To Share `Screenshot` To `gmail` or so

```
String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), yourBitmap,
                "title", null);
        Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);
        final Intent emailIntent1 = new Intent(
                android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent1.setType("text/plain");
        emailIntent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        emailIntent1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
        emailIntent1.setType("image/png");
        startActivity(Intent
                .createChooser(emailIntent1, "Send email using"));
```

pass the bitmap in the `insert.image()`

Comment: thanks..but how can i use bitmap using snapshot method and as MapView class is deprecated..getDrawingCache cannot be used..Can't think of it..

Comment: what you are trying to do ? what u want to implement ?

Comment: im building a local navigating app..that stores dynamic locations of a user in an array..and makes a polyline and at the end enables the user to save that path or map as an image for later use..So it can be share with gmail..Im a newbie to android..Later ill be going to add calorie calculator blah blah to the app..Just keep working on my project..